# Relative quaternion rotation (delta rotation) produces unstable results

Tags: mathematics, rotation, quaternion, three.js

Use case: I have a `currentRotation` quaternion and a `targetRotation` quaternion and need to calculate the relative rotation between them - as in: what rotation do I need to apply to transform an object with `currentRotation` so that it has `targetRotation`.

Common solutions say that the delta rotation can be calculated by `qDelta = qFrom.inverse() * qTo`, which I use as well and works fine for **most** cases.

However, I am often running into issues for some specific rotations -
[Codepen Example here](https://codepen.io/codepenAtiX/pen/KqeYjN?editors=0011) (I'm using three.js and coffeescript).

---

While a relative rotation around the z-axis works fine:

```
qFrom = (new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromAxisAngle new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 2 * (Math.PI / 6)
qTo = (new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromAxisAngle new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 5 * (Math.PI / 6)
qExp = (new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromAxisAngle new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 3 * (Math.PI / 6)
qDelta = calculateRelativeRotation(qFrom, qTo)
qResult = qDelta.clone().multiply(qFrom)
```

*Sane case results (delta):  expected x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: 90.0°, got x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: 90.0°*

*Sane case results (result): expected x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: 150.0°, got x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: 150.0°*

... a more complicated rotation does not work out - the combination of `qFrom` and `qDelta` does not result in the expected `qTo` rotation:

```
eFrom = new THREE.Euler(0, 170 * dToR, 10 * dToR, 'XYZ')
eTo = new THREE.Euler(0, 170 * dToR, -10 * dToR, 'XYZ')
eExp = new THREE.Euler(0, 0, -20 * dToR, 'XYZ')
```

*Problematic case results (delta): expected x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: -20.0°, got x: 0.0°, y: 0.0°, z: -20.0°*

*Problematic case results (result): expected x: -180.0°, y: 10.0°, z: 170.0°, got x: 176.5°, y: 9.4°, z: -149.7°*

*expected result quaternion (qTo): {'_x':-0.086,'_y':0.992,'_z':-0.007,'_w':0.086}*
*

*actual result quaternion: {'_x':0.257,'_y':0.962,'_z':-0.007,'_w':0.086}*

---

Inverting the calculated delta rotations helps for some cases, but doesn't cover all cases.

What am I missing?

Comment: TLDR: Quaternion math is weird. I don't know what the problem is (i.e. how to fix it, whatever "it" actually is) because quaternions aren't something I understand. I *can* tell you that quaternion multiplication is noncommutative (i.e. order matters) but that's about it.

Comment: True that. The multiplication seems to be correct, as this issue only occurs for some special cases, and generally works fine.

Comment: I figured you hadn't messed up that badly or nothing would work. But I still don't know why it won't always work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Neal on Mathematics Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354978/relative-quaternion-rotation-delta-rotation-produces-unstable-results) I found out that my code to calculate relative rotations was indeed in the wrong order (I took it from [Unity Anwers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/35541/problem-finding-relative-rotation-from-one-quatern.html) which seems *not* to be the correct way to do it within three.js) - with the tricky part being that it worked out most times. So, the correct solution to calculate a relative rotation is

**qDelta = qTo * qFrom.inverse()**

Comment: As long as you deal with unit length quaternions (which you have to for 3D orientations/rotations), the conjugate is the same as the inverse. The conjugate is faster, its basically just a copy with changing the sign for the axis-part.

Comment: If you're curious why the order flips, it's a matter of whether you apply the relative rotation in local or global space. If your question is "what relative rotation `qRel` do I need to apply to a child, so *after* its parent's rotation `qRef` is applied I get my desired result rotation `qNet`?" Then `qNet = qRef * qRel = qRef * (qRef^-1 * qNet) ∴ qRel = qRef^-1 * qNet` is correct. But if your question is "what relative rotation `qRel` do I need to apply on top of a starting rotation `qRef`" then `qNet = qRel * qRef = (qNet * qRef^-1) ∴ qRel = qNet * qRef^-1`. Both valid, just different cases.

Comment: Oops, I left off a `qRef` in the second derivation above. The world space compounding case should be `qNet = qRel * qRef = (qNet * qRef^-1) * qRef ∴ qRel = qNet * qRef^-1`